# nth-of-type inside a div not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, jasmine

I'm trying to select the first `<h6>` element inside the `#user-attributes` div with this css selector:

```
this.country = fixture.debugElement
               .query(By.css('div#user-attributes h6:nth-of-type(1) ')).nativeElement;
```

But it isn't working. Why not?

I need to then select say the 3rd and 4th `<h6>` inside the `#user-attributes` div so I'm using `:nth-of-type`.

Don't worry about the jasmine syntax, that's just how jasmine gets html elements with css.

My html:

```
<div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="card-noshadow" id="user-attributes">
    <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="row">
        <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="col-xs-12">
            <img _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="pull-xs-left icon" src="images/maps-green.png">
            <h6 _ngcontent-cvy-35="">New Zealand</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="row">
        <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="col-xs-12">
            <img _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="pull-xs-left icon" src="images/refresh.png">
            <h6 _ngcontent-cvy-35="">member since Mon Oct 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (NZDT)</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="row">
        <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="col-xs-12">
            <img _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="pull-xs-left icon" src="images/clock.png">
            <h6 _ngcontent-cvy-35="">last seen Thu Oct 13 2016 11:13:00 GMT+1300 (NZDT)</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="row">
        <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="col-xs-12">
            <img _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="pull-xs-left icon" src="images/badge.png">
            <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "active User,helper"
}--><div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" id="badges">
                <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="badge">
                    active User
                </div>
            </div><div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" id="badges">
                <div _ngcontent-cvy-35="" class="badge">
                    helper
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it not work if you were to use: `div#user-attributes .row:first-child h6` ?

Comment: Add the html **after** being processed by angular

Comment: @Dekel my other css selectors for getting other elements work so i don't think it is a timing thing

Comment: Not a question of timing, question of actual html vs css selector :)

Comment: @Dekel The html in the question is after angular has processed it isn't it? It has the _ngcontent bits in there. I got it from the chrome browser inspector

Comment: Based on your html the query `div#user-attributes h6:nth-of-type(1)` returns 3 elements, so I'm not sure you can do `.nativeElement` on that result.

Comment: Thanks @Dekel that's right, I was misunderstanding what `nth-of-type()` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot without seeing the HTML.

The main issue (probably) is that [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) works differently than you think. Elements using [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) **need to be siblings**. If the element you are targeting is nested inside other elements it won't work.

I'm guessing your markup is something like this:

```
<div id="user-attributes">
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

If so, `#user-attributes h6:nth-of-type(2)` wouldn't match the second `<h6>` because it's the **first** of type in `#user-attributes > div > h6`. The above `<h6>` are not siblings (but their parent `<div>` are).

```css
#user-attributes h6:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-attributes">
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the following markup will:

```
<div id="user-attributes">
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#user-attributes h6:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-attributes">
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

If your markup is similar to this, you'll have to move up the document tree and possibly use a different selector.

```css
#user-attributes > div:nth-of-type(2) h6 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-attributes">
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see things could get tricky with the following example:

```css
#user-attributes > div:nth-of-type(2) h6 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-attributes">
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
    <h6>Header (Why am I not red?)</h6>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6>Header</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

At this point you'd likely want to move towards adding a class to specific `<h6>`. You could continue using `nth-of-type()`, but might get a bit hairy as you'd use multiple selectors with multiple `nth-` pseudo classes per selector.

Answer (score 1):

From a CSS perspective it looks ok:

```css
div#user-attributes h6:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
div#user-attributes h6:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: green;
}
div#user-attributes h6:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-attributes">
  <h6>first</h6>
  <h6>second</h6>
  <h6>third</h6>
</div>
```

Are you sure your html is as you think it is?